# PHP Variable not acting as a reference

Tags: php, reference

```
<?php
class User {
    public $id;
    public $counter;
    public $removed;
}
$dB = json_decode(file_get_contents('dataBase.json'), true);
$dataBase = &$dB['noob'];
$userInDB = null;
$user = array('id' => (int)$_GET['id'], 'counter' => (int)$_GET['counter'], 'removed' => (bool)$_GET['removed']);
foreach ($dataBase as $usr) {
    if ($usr['id'] == $user['id']) {
        $userInDB = &$usr;
        break;
    }
}
if ($userInDB) {
    $userInDB['counter'] = $userInDB['counter'] + $user['counter'];
    $userInDB['removed'] = $user['removed'];
    print_r($userInDB);
} else {
    $dataBase[] = $user;
    print_r($dataBase);
}
if(isset($_GET['id'])) { 
    $json = json_encode($user);
    $updateddB = json_encode($dB);
    file_put_contents('dataBase.json', $updateddB);
}
?>
```

Everything works except the part where I attempt to edit a value within an array. $userInDB is changed, but the section that it refers to within $dB isn't, even though I'm pretty sure I referred to it. Someone please help, I've had my head in knots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following loop:

```
foreach ($dataBase as $usr) {
    if ($usr['id'] == $user['id']) {
        $userInDB = &$usr;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `$userInDB` is a reference to `$usr`, however `$usr` was just created by the `foreach` loop, and is is not referenced to the original array it is looping over. So say, for example, you have this very simple case:

```
foreach ($foo as $var) {
    $var++;
}
```

This does NOT affect `$foo` at all.

What you need to do is reference the `$dataBase` variable directly:

```
foreach ($dataBase as $key => $usr) {
    if ($usr['id'] == $user['id']) {
        $userInDB = &$dataBase[$key];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NooberNoob On another note, assigning variables by reference here only confuses your code in my opinion. I would remove them completely.